# Should the code for an interface contain commentaries?

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

Should a Java interface have any commentaries in its source code, or just the class that implements the interface (or both)?

Example:

```
 public interface Book{
      /**
        * Commentaries should be here?
        */
      void read();
 }

 public class Book{
      /**
        * Commentaries should be here?
        */
      void read();
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Commentaries are just to document what the code does . It is not mandatory 'per se' to compile the code . But I would suggest to put commentaries wherever necessary so that any uninitiated can understand the code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java interface should be documented.  The documentation carries through to the concrete classes that implement the interface.

Here's a great example of documenting an interface.  These are the comments from the beginning of the [List interface](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/List.java.html).  The comments not only describe what the interface does, they describe what the interface does not do.

We should all strive to write comments like these.

```
/**
 * An ordered collection (also known as a <i>sequence</i>).  The user of this
 * interface has precise control over where in the list each element is
 * inserted.  The user can access elements by their integer index (position in
 * the list), and search for elements in the list.<p>
 *
 * Unlike sets, lists typically allow duplicate elements.  More formally,
 * lists typically allow pairs of elements <tt>e1</tt> and <tt>e2</tt>
 * such that <tt>e1.equals(e2)</tt>, and they typically allow multiple
 * null elements if they allow null elements at all.  It is not inconceivable
 * that someone might wish to implement a list that prohibits duplicates, by
 * throwing runtime exceptions when the user attempts to insert them, but we
 * expect this usage to be rare.<p>
 *
 * The <tt>List</tt> interface places additional stipulations, beyond those
 * specified in the <tt>Collection</tt> interface, on the contracts of the
 * <tt>iterator</tt>, <tt>add</tt>, <tt>remove</tt>, <tt>equals</tt>, and
 * <tt>hashCode</tt> methods.  Declarations for other inherited methods are
 * also included here for convenience.<p>
 *
 * The <tt>List</tt> interface provides four methods for positional (indexed)
 * access to list elements.  Lists (like Java arrays) are zero based.  Note
 * that these operations may execute in time proportional to the index value
 * for some implementations (the <tt>LinkedList</tt> class, for
 * example). Thus, iterating over the elements in a list is typically
 * preferable to indexing through it if the caller does not know the
 * implementation.<p>
 *
 * The <tt>List</tt> interface provides a special iterator, called a
 * <tt>ListIterator</tt>, that allows element insertion and replacement, and
 * bidirectional access in addition to the normal operations that the
 * <tt>Iterator</tt> interface provides.  A method is provided to obtain a
 * list iterator that starts at a specified position in the list.<p>
 *
 * The <tt>List</tt> interface provides two methods to search for a specified
 * object.  From a performance standpoint, these methods should be used with
 * caution.  In many implementations they will perform costly linear
 * searches.<p>
 *
 * The <tt>List</tt> interface provides two methods to efficiently insert and
 * remove multiple elements at an arbitrary point in the list.<p>
 *
 * Note: While it is permissible for lists to contain themselves as elements,
 * extreme caution is advised: the <tt>equals</tt> and <tt>hashCode</tt>
 * methods are no longer well defined on such a list.
 *
 * <p>Some list implementations have restrictions on the elements that
 * they may contain.  For example, some implementations prohibit null elements,
 * and some have restrictions on the types of their elements.  Attempting to
 * add an ineligible element throws an unchecked exception, typically
 * <tt>NullPointerException</tt> or <tt>ClassCastException</tt>.  Attempting
 * to query the presence of an ineligible element may throw an exception,
 * or it may simply return false; some implementations will exhibit the former
 * behavior and some will exhibit the latter.  More generally, attempting an
 * operation on an ineligible element whose completion would not result in
 * the insertion of an ineligible element into the list may throw an
 * exception or it may succeed, at the option of the implementation.
 * Such exceptions are marked as "optional" in the specification for this
 * interface.
 *
 * <p>This interface is a member of the
 * <a href="{@docRoot}/../technotes/guides/collections/index.html">
 * Java Collections Framework</a>.
 *
 * @param <E> the type of elements in this list
 *
 * @author  Josh Bloch
 * @author  Neal Gafter
 * @see Collection
 * @see Set
 * @see ArrayList
 * @see LinkedList
 * @see Vector
 * @see Arrays#asList(Object[])
 * @see Collections#nCopies(int, Object)
 * @see Collections#EMPTY_LIST
 * @see AbstractList
 * @see AbstractSequentialList
 * @since 1.2
 */
```